# Combine two plots in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to create a ggplot that is a column plot overlayed with a line plot.  The line plot shows mean values, while the column plot shows how the mean values relate to benchmark values.  I've managed to create two separate plots in ggplot, but I'm having trouble combining them.

My line plot looks like this:

[image]

And is created using this code:

```
benchMarkLine <- ggplot(UEQScores, aes(x=Scale, y=Score, group=1)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.4, colour = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 2.4, colour = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Score", breaks = seq(0, 2.5, 0.25), limits = c(0, 2.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Scale") +
  ggtitle("Mean Scores") +
  theme_bw() + # Set black and white theme +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=10), # Centre plot title
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # Turn off major gridlines
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # Turn off minor gridlines
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, vjust=0.6),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=10))
benchMarkLine
```

My Column plot looks like this:

[image]

And was created with the following code:

```
benchmarkColPlot <- ggplot(benchmark_long, aes(x=factor(Scale, scaleLevels), y=value, fill=factor(cat, bmLevels))) + 
  geom_col(position="fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = bmColours) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Score", breaks = seq(-1.0, 1.0, 0.25), limits = c(-1, 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Scale") +
  ggtitle("Benchmark Scores") +
  theme_bw() + # Set black and white theme +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=10), # Centre plot title
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # Turn off major gridlines
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # Turn off minor gridlines
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, vjust=0.6),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=10),
        legend.title = element_blank())
benchmarkColPlot
```

How can I combine these two?  I tried inserting `geom_line(UEQScores, aes(x=Scale, y=Score, group=1)) +` above  `geom_col(position="fill") +` in the column plot code, but I just get the following error:

```
Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
```

How do I combine these two plots?

---

OK, I've given up on this - I just created the chart in Excel as it seems to be a bit easier for what I'm doing here.

Comment: You should write full arguments when you add independent `geom`. Try  `geom_line(data = UEQScores, aes(x = Scale, y = Score, group = 1))`

Comment: @atsyplenkov, trying what you suggested gives me the following error:

Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: What do you mean by combine? How do you want to combine them?

Comment: @PoGibas - I mean I want to display the line in front of the bar plot.

Comment: How does the two data sets relate? Were they derived from same source?